# Viewing web pages offline

Tags: offline

I have a lot of saved web pages that I want to view whenever I want without the page connecting to the web site (I can do this on WM). How do I do this on Android? Every time I click on the HTML file it says "no connection".

Comment: You can try [this method](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8312/2422) if you have the html page saved locally.

Comment: Maybe close this as a dupe of [How can a complete web page be saved and viewed on an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/107107/how-can-a-complete-web-page-be-saved-and-viewed-on-an-android-device)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [OffLine Browser](https://market.android.com/details?id=it.nikodroid.offline) by Nikodroid. It can save web pages (and related links) and then allows you to read them when you are offline.

Comment: This seems to work well, allows downloading things that are linked to as well, like photos.

Answer (score 2):

One can use [Pocket](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro) or [Instapaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instapaper.android) to save something from your desktop for offline reading on your mobile.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reading_list/

Answer (score 1):

You could also generate PDF files using the share feature of the Android system. I am currently researching the best way. For now I am using [Web2PDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dyndns.warenix.web2pdf&hl=de) with Chrome on my Nexus 10. Does not work perfectly with all sites though. For those that do no work yet I am using the website PDFmyURL.com.

Today I noticed hat Firefox can save PDF of whole pages by default. It is hidden in Extras...

Answer (score 0):

You can use PaperSpan app to save original page offline to SD Card. Saving links can be done through computer, and app will sync and save offline.

Comment: Do you have any connection to this app? You've posted two answers recently with it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can open MHTML files with [MHT & MHTML Viewer, Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=evansir.mhtreader) app.

I am using my file explorer to open the MHTML files using this app. Sometimes I need to use the option "Open as" to see this app as an option. Another way to open MHTML files is to browse your files using this app.

I am not affiliated to the app in any way though. Opera is also an excellent app to save (and view) MHTML files.