# How to capture screenshot of entire webpage in Android browser?

Tags: browser, screenshots

How to capture screenshot of entire webpage in Android browser like I can take in my Desktop with Help of Firefox Addon called "Fireshot"? 
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Dolphin](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) browser. It supports many extensions, two of them doing exactly what you want:

[Dolphin Screen Cut](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.ScreenCut)

[Web to PDF](https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.mgeek.mypdf)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Mobile or another browser would need to support this directly for such an extension to work.  Do you need a screenshot, or do you just need to view pages offline?  In the latter case, the answers to this question might help: [Viewing web pages offline](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8090/viewing-web-pages-offline)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox Mobile + addon [Fennec Screenshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/android/addon/fennec-screenshot/) does that job perfectly.

Comment: Not working with ffox 40

Answer (score 0):

You can use browsers that support Add-ons. For example, I use Dolphin Browser and use the add-on called "Screen Cut" / "Dolphin Screen Cut" which allows freestyle screenshot so you can rearrange and measure a certain area of the screen if you so choose it over than a whole screen capture.

You can also use Maxthon Browser which supports this.