# How to browse file:/// URLs on my Android device?

Tags: browser, file-system

I have some extensive documentation in HTML format that I want to carry around with me. On my old Gingerbread phone, I was able to save the entire "site" onto the phone's sd card and browse it with the url

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/mysite/index.html.
```

Unfortunately, this is not working with my new ICS phone (which uses Chrome as the browser); trying different urls produce either a 404 "file not found" or a 403 "access denied".

Can anyone point me to a read me on how to do this?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a correct path? Where the sdcard is mounted depends heavily on your device and ROM. Seometimes it gets mounted to multiple locations at once. See if you can find them all and test. I can only test on JB and it works fine for me in the stock browser.

Comment: Err... No, I'm not sure. That's why I asked.

Comment: You can find the exact location of a file with most file managers. (by long pressing it and then tapping Properties in Root Browser Lite for example) http://i.imgur.com/LaWon.png Try /mnt/sdcard, /sdcard, /storage/sdcard0. Make sure there's no fullstop at the end of the URI

Comment: Are you including the period at the end of the URL you've given as an example?

Comment: These questions are related: [How can I open an HTML file I have copied from PC to SD Card of Phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4775) [How can I can open local files in the default Android browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8312)

Comment: From the URLs shown by the astro file browser, I'm looking in the right place: /mnt/external1. Is it possible that the problem is permissions related? Remember, I don't always get a 404, I'm often getting a 403 - ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: `/mnt/external1` isn't the same as the `/mnt/sdcard` in the URI you have.  Assuming you've accounted for that, does `file://localhost/mnt/external1/mysite/index.html` work?

Comment: Some phones like the Galaxy Nexus show `/sdcard/` as the file path in a file browser but if you try to open the file then the path is given as `/sdcard0/`.  It's common with phones that don't have an SD slot so maybe it's the issue with your phone.

Answer (score 2):

Re-phrasing your question to reflect your real problem:

> How can I read my extensive, HTML-formatted documentation on my Android device?

there is an answer which would make it easy, comfortable, and even less storage-consuming:

You could convert the entire documentation to an eBook using [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) on your PC. A good format would be e.g. ePub. As a result, your entire documentation would be packed into a single file. Now check the playstore for a nice eBook reader (my recommendation: [Moon+ Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreader) or its payed version, [Moon+ Reader Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp)), and install it on your device. Et voila: You have your documentation available on your device. Added pluses (with Moon+ Reader): You can even set multiple bookmarks, highlight text, make annotations. And due to the integrated OPDS support and even pre-configured online libraries, you'd have a bunch of books at your fingertips.

[image: Moon Reader] [image: Moon Reader Dict]

Adding a dictionary app like [ColorDict Dictionary Wikipedia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.colordict) or [Fora Dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ngc.fora) plus some (freely available) dictionaries, you could even look up things whenever needed, online or offline, as the second screenshot<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5wTf.jpg)</sup> shows.

Answer (score 0):

You also can type in termux `xdg-open example.htm` to open your file in Chrome.