# Local files revisited: Opening local HTML files (file:///path/to/file) in Chrome on Android 4.x

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, file-system, chrome-for-android

There are [other questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/how-can-i-can-open-local-files-in-the-default-android-browser) on this same topic, but I'm finding that on 4.0.4 with my HTC One, I can open `file:///` URLs just fine with Firefox, but not with Chrome or the Android browser. Those two simply report a security error and show no content.

Is this something that changed since the 2.x era when it was apparently possible? (*edit* well I realize there was no Chrome for 2.x but ...)

Comment: On 4.2.1 the URLs work fine on Chrome and Chrome Beta, but not the builtin browser.

Comment: Hmm let me try my Nexus 7 - thanks for the info.

Comment: Possibly it is disallowed to prevent hijacking?

Comment: For Android 10 or later: [Local files revisited: Opening local HTML files (file:///path/to/file) in Chrome on Android 10.x](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220400/44325)

Answer (score 3):

The issue was user error stemming from the less-than-obvious way the Android OS file system works. Everything visible in the file system is under a top-level (the *real* top) directory called "sdcard".  Thus, `file:///` URLs only work for paths like `file:///sdcard/foo/bar`.

I'll add with questionable relevance that if you haven't installed the app "AirDroid", you should. I found it while looking around for answers to a related problem.

Comment: I get: "Access to the file was denied" for the extSdCard.

Comment: what path must one use for internal storage??

Comment: @FedorSteeman it's in the answer above.

Comment: thanks. I was getting confused over the fact that my unit didn't have an sd card, so it didn't make sense to me to go to the "sdcard".