# Hyperlink in HTML do not open (video) file locally W/O internet

Tags: chrome-for-android

on my samsung Galaxy Tab A, copied a .htm file. this file has some links. These links are video files which are on same location that of .htm file. I tried relative/ absolute path. I tried http://localhost. I tried simple http server. Nothing worked. Simple http server only works sometime when internet is available. Many times I received message about:blank#blocked

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Local files revisited: Opening local HTML files (file:///path/to/file) in Chrome on Android 10.x](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220400/44325)

Comment: Though same type of several issues is been discussed, but this is bit different. my html is in Android (local fie) and the HREF location is also in same device, rather in same folder. but hyperlink does not open a relative/ absolute path. http://localhost didn't work. simple http server didn't work (should work without internet).

Comment: The dupe is related to the strict storage permission since Android 10/11 (Galaxy Tab A started with Android 9 and upgradeable to 11). I can't tell if Simple HTTP Server still works or not, but possibly not anymore. AFAIU, you can't put local files anywhere anymore, it's only accessible from the Download folder now. Otherwise, could you [edit] and provide some examples of the location and HREF you used?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. But i put my files in download folder. Also HTML page on same level. referring video file (HREF) by relative and absolute path. No success.