# How can I bookmark a local file on Android Chrome browser?

Tags: chrome-for-android, bookmarks

I have a HTML file stored on the memory card of my Android phone. I can open it in my browser (Chrome) but cannot bookmark it -- the URL is `content://com.google.android.blah.blah...` (I was expecting `file://...`) and appears to expire after some time.

Howe can I get a permanent bookmark to a local file?

Comment: Which version of Android are you using? Have you tried to input the location manually as `file:///storage/emulated/0/...`?

Comment: @l3l_aze `file://` protocol only works for certain directories on Android 10+, see [Local files revisited: Opening local HTML files (file:///path/to/file) in Chrome on Android 10.x](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220400/local-files-revisited-opening-local-html-files-file-path-to-file-in-chrome)

Comment: A bit strange the URL starts with `content://`. That means it's accessing a [content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics#ContentURIs). Is that from an app?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Android 10. I used to be able to set a bookmark in FireFox even after upgrade. That stopped working as well.

The only solution I have found is to use a HTML Reader. Here is a link to one I have found to work well. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.vineetsirohi.htmlreader