# Local HTML file links cannot be followed

Tags: file-system, browser, html

**Background:**

I use my tablet for Geocaching, specifically to have cache listings available in the field. For this purpose, I have a program called Geocaching Swiss Army Knife (also known as GSAK) generate HTML files on a regular basis, which I have copied onto a memory card. Normally, when I go out into the field and look up a cache, I have the index file as the home page in a browser, and then follow the links from the index to the actual cache listing.
I have been using a Dell Venue 8 for this task, but the battery finally died (won't take a charge),
and Dell has gotten out of the Android tablet market, so I bought a Samsung S7 Fe to replace it.

**Problem:**

Unfortunately, I can load the index file fine, and all the files are there, but none of the multiple browsers I've tried will allow me to navigate beyond the index file. The error I get is:

`"Content links are blocked", it may have been moved, edited, or deleted`

(This varies by browser, but the gist is the same)

Is there a setting that will enable the browser to follow links between local files?

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [Local files revisited: Opening local HTML files (file:///path/to/file) in Chrome on Android 10.x](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220400/44325)