# Is there a way to view HTML files/sites on the Nexus 7/Android 4.2.2?

Tags: files, offline, html

I am trying to get my new Nexus 7 to display my offline web site that I made with HTML, CSS and Javascript. I have been looking for a way to display my site off the tablet as sort of a demo for people to play with. A fully working site, no screen shots but something interactive.

I kinda know how to put the files on my Nexus, and by that I mean I can get it on there but then I cant find it when I browse though it. I put it in the download folder but I don't see the folder. It's not zipped or compressed, i'ts just the folder in there. Any advice would be great.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [How can I open an HTML file I have copied from PC to SD Card of Phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4775)

Comment: Also possibly relevant: [How can I can open local files in the default Android browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/8312)

Answer (score 1):

Once you transfer files to your Nexus 7 use one of these apps to get to the files:

Solid Explorer or ES File Explorer

explained here:

http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-2012/201344-how-view-files.html

NEXT STEP:

To View on the html file on your Nexus 7 use the HTML Viewer app.

Would love a quicker solution, but this works!