# Open Web Page in Browser (not on SD card)

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, browser, internal-storage, chrome-for-android, html

My question is similar to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/how-can-i-can-open-local-files-in-the-default-android-browser), but my HTML file and resources are not on an SD card, as my phone does not accept SD cards. It is currently at `file:///Download/AnotherFolder/here.html`. I have resources like images and javascript in a subfolder. How can I run this is in a browser, preferably Chrome? Just entering `file:///Download/AnotherFolder/here.html` does not work in Chrome.

Comment: Is there an error message your seeing in Chrome?

Comment: It says the page is not available (net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it in the internal SD card? Try `file://mnt/sdcard/Download/AnotherFolder/here.html`.

Comment: Or better yet, use `file:///sdcard/Download/...`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your device has no SD card slot, there is an internal SD and memory hard coded into your device. So the path to your html file would be something similar to `file:///mnt/sdcard/dir.....` or `file:///storage/sdcard0/dir......` You can find it using [a file manager app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file%20manager&c=apps).