# HTML Viewer seems not running the website's Javascripts

Tags: browser, files, html, opera-mini, javascript

I have an offline saved htm web page on sdcard to test Javascript. The default render on my phone seems to be HTML Viewer. But when I tried to open the page, the code didn't run. I know this because there's some html tag in the page I was added to detect this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> /* my Javascripts */ </script>
<noscript> The current browser can't run Javascript. </noscript>
```

which displays on the page: "The current browser can't run Javascript."

So how can I enable Javascript in HTML Viewer? Both Opera and Browser are somehow can't found out the file when I typed in the address textbox:

```
file://localhost/sdcard/page.htm
```

The problem exist on almost any phone. But the later just works on some of my phone. Another not.

Comment: Don't use localhost. Let me know if the answers here helps: [Open Web Page in Browser (not on SD card)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48246/open-web-page-in-browser-not-on-sd-card)

Comment: Both localhost and mnt/ can't open the site in opera and browsers on some of my phones. But others can. I still don't know why...

Comment: Have you enabled JavaScript on your browsers? Check the settings, maybe it's disabled.

Comment: I can't find out a context menu of HTML Viewer. Browser has a context menu, and I can change Javascript settings from there. But Browser can't found the file on sdcard. So HTML Viewer is the only choice. And it seems not running Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

HTML Viewer is part of Android OS and i felt it has no javascript engine, just HTML Viewer not HTML Browser.

Try to access it to your browser

file:///sdcard/yourfile.html