# App for running a (simple) web server on Android?

Tags: html, documents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Viewing web pages offline.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8090/viewing-web-pages-offline)

Hi,

I just got a new Acer tablet, and was looking forward to reading HTML files in addition to PDF on my tablet during my commute: case in point being the Android documentation which is available in offline form in the `doc/` directory in the sdk install.

So I copied the `doc/` folder from my PC to my tablet, and browsed to it using Astro, but was saddened to find that HTML files on the SD card are not easily accessible by the browser, which brings me to my question:

Is there an app (preferably open source), which can provide a basic web server (only localhost, simply serving HTML, JS, CSS and image files) so I can access files by typing URLs such as `http://localohost/android-docs/index.html` ?

I have looked at [iJetty](http://code.google.com/p/i-jetty/), but it seems to be doing too much. I just want to serve files, not do much Java.

Thanks in advance.

-A

Comment: Rather than asking for apps, we prefer questions that ask how to solve a specific problem. In your case it seems you just want to open local HTML files and have them properly rendered. As such, the accepted answer to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4775/open-html-file-from-sd-card) would seem to solve your problem.

Comment: I think a web server is too extreme to solve a simple problem like viewing files.  See if the other question can help you.  Edit: Good timing Al.

Comment: Also related (linked in the question Al added): [How can I can open local files in the default Android browser?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8312/how-can-i-can-open-local-files-in-the-default-android-browser)

Comment: Hi all: Your points are valid. Indeed, I should have asked how to access local HTML files in the browser. The `file:///` method worked for me. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No...close it instead.

Answer (score -2):

I do not know if this will help you but.... I have a similar problem with my Droid X.  This is what I did--it might work for you:

1. On your home computer or notebook, download Opera, the free browser.  Install.
2. Go Opera Unite within the browser.
3. Install the proxy server (may be named web proxy).  The Unite web server app will also work.
4. Follow the instructions.  Choose a folder on an attached drive (example C:\nameoffolder)
5. Fire up the app.  Note the URl which is generated.
6. If you did this correctly, you now have a webserver installed within the Opera browser.  You can configure whether you want this to be public or private.
7. Now, go to the Acer tablet.  Open up any web browser --it need not be the Opera browser.
8. Insert the URL you previously copied.

   1. If your html files are hyperlinked, you should be home free.

As long as Opera browser with the Unite apps are running on the "original" computer, you can access them as a web page on your tablet.

Good luck!

Comment: He wants to read the files offline, not have to connect to a PC.